# Modification of a constant reference

Tags: c++, constants, ref

This is a theoretical question me and my colleagues were discussing about. I will soon try it myself but i thought its an interessting topic for a newbie.

Lets imagine there is a baseclass "VEHICLE" and derived classes like "CAR" and "TRUCK"...
(where "VEHICLE" is a abstract class and can not be instantiated).

So far so good. Now you create a car named A: *car A;*
and a const reference to A named B: *const car& B = A;*

Let's suppose class "CAR" has a function called broken_door. My questions is now the following: When I call *A.broken_door();* 
what would happen to B, since B is a constant and a reference object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `B` is a constant _reference_ and thus eqivalent to `A`. What should happen to `B` actually? It's still a _reference_.

Comment: `B` would continue to refer to `A`. That is what a reference does. Refer to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing would happen to `B`. It would continue to refer to `A`, which will have been modified.

The `const` means that `B` can't be used to modify the object it refers to. It doesn't mean that the object can't change by other means.

Answer (score 2):

`B` is just a reference to `A` that gives you a different name for the same object.

`const car& B = A;` does not magically turn  `A` into a constant object that cannot be modified, it just means you can't modify it *through `B`*.

You can still change the object by modifying `A` directly, or through another (non-const) pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1):

"B" and "A" are different names for the same thing.
The difference between them is that you can't refer to the thing as "B" if you want to change it.
(A "const reference" is not a reference to an object that won't change, it's a reference through which change is prohibited.)

A slightly flawed analogy: you can use the name "molbdnilo" as a "const reference" to me (because it refers to me, but you have no ability to modify me).
Nevertheless, if I change my stackoverflow profile, you will still see the change if you look at it.